# How to determine if number represented by char array will overflow an int?

Tags: c, int, arrays, integer-overflow

Suppose that I have a char array of arbitrary length that only holds ASCII representations of numerical digits used to form a number in each entry of the array. For example

```
char my_array[10] = { '5', '2', '4', '7', 5, '1', '0', '8', '9', '\0' };
```

represents the number

> 524751089

when extracted from the array with `atoi()` from `stdlib.h.`

The issue I am facing is how to check and see if the number represented by the char array will overflow an unsigned int when I attempt to extract it. Any recommendations on how to validate the array before passing it to get extracted and turned into an unsigned int would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use `strtol` or `strtoll` and check the range + errors.

Comment: First check the length, if they're equal do comparison per character from the front

Comment: @VladLazarenko: It might overflow a long or long long too.

Comment: @remyabel: Not sure how `strlen` would help. You need to convert base 10 ASCII to 32-bit binary number. Length of ASCII string does not mean much here.

Comment: @marcadian: There's only one string. I don't know what you're talking about comparing to.

Comment: @user2357112: I am not saying it cannot. But it checks for overflow and provides error code for users to use.

Comment: How portable do you need to be?  Are you willing to make any assumptions about the size of your unsigned ints?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Checking the range isn't enough; you'd also need to check errno.

Comment: compare with the maximum possible value (2 ^ 32 - 1 for 32 bit unsigned int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strtoul()` function will convert to an `unsigned long` (which must have at least as much range as `unsigned int`), and allows you to detect out-of-range values.  You can further compare the result against `UINT_MAX` (from `<limits.h>`) to determine if it is within range of `unsigned int`:

```
unsigned long result;

errno = 0;
result = strtoul(my_array, NULL, 10);

if ((result == ULONG_MAX && errno == ERANGE) || result > UINT_MAX)
{
    /* Out of range of unsigned int */
}
else
{
    /* Within range of unsigned int */
}
```

Comment: `strtol` can also return `ULONG_MIN` or `0` on some systems :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I'm not calling `strtol()`, I'm calling `strtoul()`.  And a version that returns 0 on an out-of-range input is not standard conforming (and there *is* no `ULONG_MIN` ;)

Comment: This suggestion works for my application. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::strtol` or `std::strtoll`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) and check their return values:

[image]

Note: As these two functions tend to convert it to a `long`/`long long`, you may also need to check the return value is larger than `UINT_MAX` if successfully.

Comment: `strtol()` and `strtoll()` are not useful here, because the positive range of `unsigned int` may be greater than that of  `long int` or `long long int` (consider the case where `int`, `long int` and `long long int` and their unsigned equivalents are all 64 bits wide).

Comment: This question is tagged "C".  This means no exception will be raised (obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You could use snprintf to populate a character buffer with UINT_MAX.  Then there three possible cases for the length:

1. len(UINT_MAX) > len(your buffer) means that your buffer is ok.
2. len(UINT_MAX) < len(your buffer) means that your buffer is not going
   to fit.
3. len(UINT_MAX) == len(your buffer) means that you use strcmp to compare the two.

Where len(UINT_MAX) is the number of ASCII characters UINT_MAX took to print.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void check_number(const char *s)
{
        long long v;
        char *e;

        v = strtoll(s, &e, 10);
        if (errno != 0 || *e != '\0' || v < 0 || v > UINT_MAX) {
                fputs("Nope, that's not gonna fly!\n", stderr);
        }
        fputs("The number is OK!\n", stdout);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const char *number;

        if (argc < 2) {
                fputs("Please specify a number in base 10 to check\n", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        number = argv[1];
        check_number(number);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This fails for numbers greater than `LLONG_MAX` but less than or equal to `UINT_MAX` (if any exist, which they might on an implementation where `int`, `long` and `long long` are all the same size).